# Deploying Wordpress with Portainer and editing afterwards

Tags: docker, wordpress, docker-compose

I have deployed a Wordpress container through Portainer and all is well with the container actually working.  However, when I try to find the files locally to edit, I cannot.  Did I miss a step?  What do I need to do to put the data on my local Mac file system or create symlinks during the deployment of the container?

When I utilize `docker compose up -d` to deploy the stack, I can see the files start to appear in my VS Code workspace.

I know I can `docker exec -it name bash` into the container, but I cannot see and edit that locally within my MacOS file system.

Thanks community!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could utilize VSCODE ext. "Remote SSH" and connect after setting up SSH keys for my development machine and the host.

Secondly, found that I wasn't setting the volume's properly back to my system.  /path/to was left off and was used by named volumes.